# How to send a battery-including electrical stove from Thailand to Vietnam?

Tags: thailand, postal-system, vietnam

I have an Electrical stove that I charge directly from an electricity socket, then turn on, then set heating level by Watt (800 Watt is the medium level, I think) and it also contains battery for a large cooling fan instilled under the stove and keep working some time after I turn off that appliance to ensure cooling off the appliance.

This electric stove appliance costed me about 1,900 Baht at Big C.

I might need to move to Vietnam soon and I want to take the electrical stove with me (along with a pan and pot).

### My problem

Thaipost doesn't allow to send battery-containing goods → I was told something like:

> nothing with batteries, noting flammable and no liquids (besides water I guess).

To solve that problem I thought to take it along with my laptop (holding both of them in all checkings) but I believe this will be quite frustrating and also dangerous because I might have to carry a large backpack and a smaller backpack with both laptop case and electrical stove bag.

### My question

Before I leave to Vietnam, I would like the send the electrical stove to an hotel address there:
How to send a battery-including electrical stove from Thailand to Vietnam?

### Update after answer

It seems to me I was wrong --- the electrical stove doesn't have a battery; it's cooling system just keep working after heating body is shuttled down --- if it is taken out of electricity while just cooling it will just stop working so because there is no battery, I could indeed send it with Thaipost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it will be cheaper to buy a new one in Vietnam, unless this one has some sentimental value for you thats what I would do.

If not both UPS and DHL allows to ship devices that includes batteries between Thailand and Vietnam with the correct papers prepared, but I am a bit confused about their rules for used devices as oppose to new ones and even when calling them to check I got different answers from Vietnam and Thailand.